# In Linux, is there a command for converting a CSV file into an SQLite file?

Tags: linux, command-line, csv, sqlite

Is there a Linux command that will convert a CSV file into an SQLite database, sometime like:

```
csv2sqlite input.csv output.sqlite [optional_table_schema]
```

Or does sqlite3 have command-line options that will do this?

(I wrote some code to process/clean some text files. At the end, I may call convert a CSV file into an SQLite database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a CSV file `my_input.csv` with the following data. Note that the pipe ("|") is the default delimiter in SQLite.

```
apple|red
banana|yellow
celery|green
```

Below are two methods of creating an SQLite database `my_db.sqlite` with the above input file.

Method 1: Paste the following code onto the command line. Or paste it into an executable file and run the file in bash.

```
sqlite3 my_db.sqlite "CREATE TABLE my_table(food TEXT, color TEXT)"
sqlite3 my_db.sqlite ".import my_input.csv my_table"
```

Method 2: Paste the following Python code into a file and run it using Python 2.6.6, 2.7.1, or 3.1.3.

```
import subprocess

args = [
    "sqlite3",
    "my_db.sqlite",
    "CREATE TABLE my_table(food TEXT, color TEXT)",
    ]

subprocess.call(args)

args = [
    "sqlite3",
    "my_db.sqlite",
    ".import my_input.csv my_table",
    ]

subprocess.call(args)
```

Answer (score 8):

If your csv is very very simple (no quoting, escaping, etc) you can import it with the sqlite shell:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Edit: But it probably isn't, so I think you'll need to convert the file first. If your csv file no ascii double quotes, or newlines, you can convert it into a file that sqlite can import with this command:

```
csvtool -u '`' cat csv.csv
```

(replacing the ` above with some character that's not in your data)

That removes quotes from around fields that have double quotes in them. csvtool doesn't seem to be smart about escaping. It doesn't have any options I can see about handling escaping, and any fields that have " in them, it just leaves as is with the quotes around.

anyway, then you can use the link above for how to import to sqlite. Just make sure you set the same separator

Comment: But do I have to manually open sqlite3 and type the import command? Is there a way to do this functionality from a script?

Comment: @Winston C. Yang: I assume you can just pass those commands to stdin of that program (eg echo "create database ..." | sqlite3 database.db) or, by the looks of the man page (http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sqlite3/) you can pass the commands as the final parameter

Answer (score 0):

Have had pretty good luck using the import feature in Sqlitebrowser http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check out termsql. https://gitorious.org/termsql
https://gitorious.org/termsql/pages/Home

It converts text to SQL on the command line. (CSV is just text)

Example:

cat textfile | termsql -o sqlite.db

By default the delimiter is whitespace, so to make it work with CSV that
is using commata, you'd do it like this:

cat textfile | termsql -d ',' -o sqlite.db

alternatively you can do this:

termsql -i textfile -d ',' -o sqlite.db

By default it will generate column names "COL0", "COL1", if
you want it to use the first row for the columns names you do this:

termsql -i textfile -d ',' -1 -o sqlite.db

If you want to set custom column names you do this:

termsql -i textfile -d ',' -c 'id,name,age,color' -o sqlite.db

Comment: I installed this on Arch Linux, and it's good, but not for converting csv to sql. The problem is that it doesn't know to ignore commas and returns that are enclosed by quotes. It creates a new item for every comma and a new row for every return even when the commas and returns are supposed to be data because they are part of a double quoted string.